# Find all instances of a certain class

Tags: purescript

Is there a way to pragmatically enumerate all instances of a class? In Pursuit I can see that Extend has 2 instances, but what if I have other instances declared in my code base? Can it be done at least in `pulp repl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware no. But here's a cheap little hack using `jq` that might tell you what you need to know:

```
jq '..|.TypeInstanceRef? | select(. != null) | map(..|.Ident?) | add' output/*/externs.json
```

Run from the the root of your project this should print out all known instance names. And seeing as we conventionally name instances `classType` (e.g. `showBoolean`) you should be able to `grep` for the class(es) you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you! This should be enough for me :)